# Ocultar ventana CMD rclone

Tags: cmd, batch, windows10

les comento mi duda.

Actualmente tengo rclone en mi PC con widnows para conectarme a un almacenamiento tipo S3 y que se monte como disco local.

Para ello ejecuto este comando

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k cd c:\rclone & rclone mount iDrive:private-data/ X: --vfs-cache-mode full
```

Para que se conectara de forma automática al iniciar lo guarde como acceso directo.

El problema es que esto me deja abierta una ventana CMD con la leyenda "Rclone service has been started", si cierro esta ventana en automático deja de existir la unidad.

¿Como puedo hacer que se ejecute el montaje de rclone pero sin que tenga que estar abierta una ventana de CMD?

Comment: as probado @echo off al principio y exit al final

Answer (score 0):

Entre "rclone" y "mount" escribe "--no-console"

Con eso a mí me ha funcionado. Espero que te sirva